# Very slow Fortran code with mingw gcc 4.7.0 (as compared to 4.4.0)

Tags: mingw, gfortran

I have a library written in Fortran 90, and several applications in C and C++ which use it. Earlier I used MinGW GCC 4.4.0 (which was make up by me from several binary archives that I downloaded from mingw.org) to compile them all.

Today I downloaded newest MinGW (GCC 4.7.0, net install) and rebuilt all my code. Surprisingly application started to work very slow - approximately 30 times slower or more. Meanwhile both recompiled version and restored from backup work similar - it seems that the problem is with gfortran DLL, which was taken from PATH (i. e. new MinGW irrespectively of the application version).

What could be a source of the problem, and how it can be resolved? Temporarily I've returned to old MinGW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After returning to this problem I was successful to find a workaround (but not the reason).

In my program some computation-extensive fortran subroutine was called from several threads on C side. For some reason on mingw-gfortran 4.6.2 or 4.7.0 this  *slows* the program by 15 times, while on 4.4.0 program fasters. If subroutine is being called only from one thread, 4.7.0 becomes equals to 4.4.0 in the terms of speed.

As currently the speed is sufficient for me I limited caller environment to 1 thread.